# android actionbar tab viewpage AsyncTask first tab is empty when started

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

it is a few days I try to solve this problem whitout success. Please help me.

I use the tabs navigation with viewpager.There are four fragments. I use async task for download the data I need to put in the view. when the app is started, the first fragments is ampty. But when i swipe to the second or the third, they have data. if i swipe from the second to the first, it has data too. so i guess i may be something wrong with **notifyDataSetChanged**, but i tried and it doesnt work.

MainActivity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        //private ArrayList hasLoadedPages = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
  }

public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            //case 0:
            //    return new LaunchpadSectionFragment();

            default:
                Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                return fragment;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String str="";
        if (position==0){
            str = "one";
        }else if(position==1){
            str = "two";
        }else if(position==2){
            str = "three";
        }else if(position==3){
            str = "four";
        }
        return str;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged()
    {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}

public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_dummy, container, false);
        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        mCid = args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
        mNewsData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
        mNewsList = (ListView)getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mNewsListAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this.getActivity(), mNewsData, R.layout.newslist_item, 
                new String[]{"newslist_item_title","newslist_item_digest","newslist_item_source","newslist_item_ptime"}, 
                new int[]{R.id.newslist_item_title,R.id.newslist_item_digest,R.id.newslist_item_source,R.id.newslist_item_ptime});
        View loadMoreLayout = this.getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.loadmore, null);
        mNewsList.setAdapter(mNewsListAdapter);
        mNewsList.addFooterView(loadMoreLayout);
        mNewsList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewsDetailsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                intent.putExtra("newsDate", mNewsData);
                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        mLoadMoreBtn = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.loadmore_btn);
        mLoadMoreBtn.setOnClickListener(loadMoreListener);

        loadNewsAsyncTask = new LoadNewsAsyncTask();
        loadNewsAsyncTask.execute(mCid,0,true);
    }
}

private static class LoadNewsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Integer>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        mLoadMoreBtn.setText(R.string.loadmore_txt);
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Object... params)
    {
        return getSpeCateNews((Integer)params[0],mNewsData,(Integer)params[1],(Boolean)params[2]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)
    {
        switch (result)
        {
        case NONEWS:
            mLoadMoreBtn.setText(R.string.no_news);
            break;
        case NOMORENEWS:
            mLoadMoreBtn.setText(R.string.no_more_news);
            break;
        case LOADERROR:
            mLoadMoreBtn.setText(R.string.load_news_failure);
            break;
        }
        mNewsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mLoadMoreBtn.setText(R.string.loadmore_btn);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had solved this problem

Comment: every adapter in fragment should be unique

Answer (score 0):

**You are using FragmentPagerAdapter please change it to FragmentStatePagerAdapter and run again**

Difference between FragmentPagerAdapter and FragmentStatePagerAdapter

About FragmentPagerAdapter Google's guide says:

This version of the pager is best for use when there are a handful of typically more static fragments to be paged through, such as a set of tabs. The fragment of each page the user visits will be kept in memory, though its view hierarchy may be destroyed when not visible. This can result in using a significant amount of memory since fragment instances can hold on to an arbitrary amount of state. For larger sets of pages, consider FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

And about FragmentStatePagerAdapter:

This version of the pager is more useful when there are a large number of pages, working more like a list view. When pages are not visible to the user, their entire fragment may be destroyed, only keeping the saved state of that fragment. This allows the pager to hold on to much less memory associated with each visited page as compared to FragmentPagerAdapter at the cost of potentially more overhead when switching between pages.